# How to add blank lines in between items of an ordered list?

Tags: css, html

I currently have the following HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
</ol>
```

That produces the usual result:

1. Foo
2. Bar
3. Baz

I would like to add a blank line in between each list item, so that the output appears like this:

1. Foo
2. Bar
3. Baz

This can be done by adding two `<br>` tags before each closing `</li>` tag. However, it's ugly and inelegant.

Is there a better way to achieve the same result in HTML or CSS?

Comment: You can add margin or padding using CSS.

Answer (score 4):

You could increase the margin or padding on each `li` to your liking. eg.

```
li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Yep. And if you're concerned about space after the last one you can use `li:not(:last-child)`

Answer (score 2):

you add padding in `ol`  `li`

```css
ol li{
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: you can increase your padding li with your requirement wise

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.mylist> li{
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="mylist">
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try to increase the line-height

```
li {
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

have a look at fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/thanseeh/rh7vqL96/2/

Comment: If a line item wraps, though, this spacing will also affect the line item internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pre` tag. No need for the css

```html
<ol>
  <pre>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
    </pre>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding to add some blank space between each item

```
<ol class="myclass">
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
</ol>

.myclass li{
   padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.myclass li:last-child{
   padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```